# How to retrieve the X- and Y- axis of a Point2D?

Tags: java, arrays, function, coordinates

How do I return the X and Y axis of a Point2D if I have something like this?:

```
Point2D point1 = new Point2D.Double(15, 15);
```

Can't seem to call `getX()` or `getY()` on this for some reason.

Complete code:

```
Point2D point1 = new Point2D.Double(15, 15);
double x = getX(point1);
double y = getY(point2);
```

Comment: Can you post the exact code you're writing where you're calling `getX()` and `getY()`? That should compile...

Comment: To call a method on an object, the syntax is object.method(), not method(object). So you want point1.getX().

Comment: I am dumb as a rock...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong syntax for invoking the `getX()` and `getY()` methods. Try writing this instead:

```
double x = point1.getX();
double y = point2.getY();
```